# Using pyviz in a jupyternotebook as a form, put input in nested list and show contents

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pyviz

im trying to use pyviz in a jupyter notebook to create some sort of form for others to populate with data.
this data then is to be saved to a nested list on the click of the save button. then you repeat it for every person.

then i need a button to show the current input of the nested list.

can someone point me in the right direction?so far ive got only the input fields, the list is always empty.

```
# companies at which people are working
company = ['wal', 'even', 'foot']
class Company(param.Parameterized):
    # dropdown of company
    company = param.ObjectSelector(objects=company)
    # name of person
    personname = param.String(doc="name")
    # age of person
    age = param.Number(0)
    # save to list button
    save_btn = param.Action(lambda self:self.param.trigger('save_btn'),doc="""Save""")
    # show list
    show_btn = param.Action(lambda self: self.param.trigger('show_btn'),doc="""Show dicitonary""")
    # dict which collects all input
    all_persons = []
    # return content of dict
    @param.depends('show_btn')
    def show_list(self):
        return self.all_persons
    # save form content to dict
    @param.depends('save_btn')
    def save_to_list(self):
        temp_list = []
        temp_list.append[self.company]
        temp_list.append[self.personname]
        temp_list.append[self.age]
run = Company()

pn.Column(run.param.company, run.param.personname,     run.param.age,run.param.save_btn,run.param.show_btn, run.show_list)

# desired nested list
# [['wal', "bob", "34"], ["foot", "anna", "56"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains a few typos and loose ends. From top to bottom:

- `all_persons` is defined as empty list, but never connected to the temp list created in the method `save_to_list()`
- `@param.depends(...)` is missing `watch=True`, e.g. `@param.depends('show_btn', watch=True)`
- `show_list()` returns `self.all_persons`, but this variable is never used anywhere

E.g.:

```py
company = ['A', 'B'] # simplified code
class Company(param.Parameterized):
    company = param.ObjectSelector(default=company[0], objects=company)
    person_name = param.String(doc="name")
    age = param.Number(0)

    save_btn = param.Action(lambda self: self.save_to_list() , doc="""Save""") # no need for param.trigger here...
    print_btn = param.Action(lambda self: self.print_list() , doc="""Print""") # no need for param.trigger here...

    all_persons = [] # starts with an empty list

    # no need for param.depends, as the method directly is called via param.Action, 
    def save_to_list(self):
        print('safe to list: {}, {}, {}'.format(self.company, self.person_name, self.age))
        temp_list = []
        temp_list.append(self.company) # use () for append, not []
        temp_list.append(self.person_name)
        temp_list.append(self.age)
        print('temp_list: {}'.format(temp_list))
        self.all_persons.append(temp_list)

    # no need for param.depends, as the method is directly called via param.Action, 
    def print_list(self):
        print('all_persons: {}'.format(self.all_persons))

run = Company()

layout = pn.Row(run.param)
layout.app() # to see print statements in a notebook, use the server variant via 'app()'
```